# How to get git-format-patch to generate a single patch file without number

Tags: git

I've a specific list of revisions output by `git rev-list` and now I wanted to generate one patch file for each of revision from that list. I thought of passing each of the revision to `git format-patch -1`. But this generates the patch file named `0001-blah-blah.patch`. I don't want `format-patch` to number a single patch for me; I'd just like it to generate `blah-blah.patch` instead.

Is there a way to get this done using `git format-patch` alone? Or is the only way to rename the file once the patch is generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to work it around using this snippet:

```
git rev-list ... |
xargs bash -c '
  let "n = 0"
  for sha; do
    printf -v name "%04d-%s.patch" "$n" "$(git show -s --format=format:%f "$sha")"
    git format-patch --stdout -1 "$sha" > "patches/$name"
    let "n++"
  done
' bash
```

Comment: Upvoted for seeing it through, but it seems like it would've been easier to just use `rename`. :)

Comment: Mm, I don't see much benefit. Generating a zero-extended 4-digit number , replacing the 0001- in the output file name of `format-patch`... Meh...